# Facebook integration with dot net

Tags: c#, facebook

I want to share question and answer from my web application using c#.net to Facebook. I have used Gaph API for this. But the problem is that only that user can share who has development account on Facebook. Other user cannnot share the question on their facebook wall. Any Solutions?

Comment: What error message are you getting? Is your application still in sandbox mode (which would prevent regular users from accessing it)?

Answer (score 0):

It definitely looks like sandbox mode is enabled.  Please check your sandbox mode setting. @lgy is correct to tell first to check the sandbox mode or also check the permission for that API.